# Foreach - show the number of items

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code to count the objects in the foreach loop (images in a gallery):

```
<?php $images = get_field('galerie'); if( $images ): ?>
      <?php $i=1; foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
      <?php echo $i++; ?> 
      <?php endforeach; ?>   
<?php endif; ?>
```

So when i have 4 items (images) it gives me

> 1 2 3 4

But i need only the highest number like:

> 4

when i have 4 imgages. Any idea how do i get this number?

Comment: Simple. Just use [`count()`](http://php.net/count): `echo count($images)`. Or if you want to loop for some other reason, just move `<?php echo $i++; ?>` outside `<?php endforeach; ?>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the images ?

```
<?php
    $images = get_field('galerie');
    if($images && is_array($images)) { // in case get_galerie returns null or empty strings when no images...
        echo count($images);
    }
?>
```

Also, no need to put `<?php ... ?>` tags on each line.

Enclose a whole block of PHP code into this tag, it's far more readable, and works the same.

Comment: I don't know what your `get_field('galerie')` does. But if it's supposed to return an array of images, its length should be 0 when no images. If `count($images)` returns 1, that means that something is added in it even when no images, which is weird/wrong.

Comment: Try `var_dump($images)` with no images to see what's in it.

Comment: this gives me "1 string(0) """

Comment: Yuck. You're type casting a string to an array in your loop. Either return a proper array or do something like [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).

Comment: Or get_field() returns an empty string when no data. You can then do what you already did in your code, that is testing your variable before calling count on it. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a count function.

```
$length = count($images);
```

Answer (score -2):

it's simple, just do it like this:

```
<?php $images = get_field('galerie'); if( $images ): ?>
  <?php $i=0; foreach( $images as $image ): ?> //$i=0 not 1
  <?php $i++; ?> 
  <?php endforeach; ?>   
  <?php echo $i; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**L.E:** just for those who down-voted my answer, I kept the users way of coding for 2 (I thought obvious) reasons:

1. He might actually need the `foreach()`
2. He might be new to PHP, and if the iterator method (`$i = 1; $i++`) is what he knows he should stick with it until he discovers something new. This is a algorithm method inherited from C, Pascal and other much "older" programming languages.

Of course, the `count()` method is faster and gives a way less pain in the behind, but this is NOT a bad way to code for a beginer.

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: Why is my answer down voted? is there something wrong with it? When you down vote, it's good practice to tell the user why you did this...

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I'm assuming the reason is that it is inefficient. Why loop through the array just to get the number of elements in it?

Comment: Your answer works as well but it is not the most efficient and 'neat' way to go. Also your current code starts at `$i=1` and will end up 1 int higher than the array actual is. (We don't hate, we provide feedback  ;-))

Comment: I explained my action in my answer.

Comment: @Stefan you are right, I edited that in my answer ... I made that mistake because I copied and pasted the code... I did not noticed that

Comment: Sorry, I disagree with this statement: "if the iterator method `($i = 1; $i++)` is what he knows he should stick with it until he discovers something new".

Comment: Why do you open and close php tag in every line? This code need one open `<?php` and one `?>` close tag.

Comment: Again, I used the code AS THE OP USED IT... I find that, for me at least, if someone tries to teach me something, I am always more receptive when that person "speaks my language".